# How to make background-image fill the div and responsive

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I want to make a div with background image and at the top there will 3 social media icon like this:

What I wanted:
[image: what i wanted]

```css
div#second-footer-container {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/0qRwdSI.png");
  width: 100% !important;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

p#socmed-container {
  text-align: center;
}

p#socmed-container a {
  padding: 0 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="second-footer-container">
  <p id="socmed-container">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/test/">
      <img id="fb-img" width="25" src="https://i.imgur.com/6ye5lwf.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/test/">
      <img id="ig-img" width="25" src="https://i.imgur.com/SEsRzFL.png" alt="Instagram" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/test/">
      <img id="twitter-img" width="25" src="https://i.imgur.com/y8o23cc.png" alt="Twitter" />
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

But the result is not look like what i wanted, my result is the background seems to only follow the main-content height:
[image: result]

I want the width 100% and the height is also 100%, and i want it to be responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-size:contain`

> Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

[background-size - reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```css
body,html{
  height: 100%;
}
div#second-footer-container {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/0qRwdSI.png");
  width: 100% !important;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

p#socmed-container {
  text-align: center;
}

p#socmed-container a {
  padding: 0 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="second-footer-container">
  <p id="socmed-container">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/test/">
      <img id="fb-img" width="25" src="https://i.imgur.com/6ye5lwf.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/test/">
      <img id="ig-img" width="25" src="https://i.imgur.com/SEsRzFL.png" alt="Instagram" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/test/">
      <img id="twitter-img" width="25" src="https://i.imgur.com/y8o23cc.png" alt="Twitter" />
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: With `background-position: 50% 50%`

Comment: it make makes the width only fill less than 50% of the div while the height is still the same [result](https://i.imgur.com/4eVAHVg.png)

Comment: Look at my example - I added `body,html{height: 100%}`, otherwise the containing div height is small and won't take 100% of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```css
#second-footer-container{
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/0qRwdSI.png");
  width: 100% !important;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#socmed-container{
  text-align: center;
}
#socmed-container a{
  padding: 0 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="second-footer-container">
  <p id="socmed-container">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/test/">
      <img id="fb-img"
           width="25"
           src="https://i.imgur.com/6ye5lwf.png"
           alt="Facebook"
       />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/test/">
      <img id="ig-img"
           width="25"
           src="https://i.imgur.com/SEsRzFL.png"
           alt="Instagram"
       />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/test/">
      <img id="twitter-img"
           width="25"
           src="https://i.imgur.com/y8o23cc.png"
           alt="Twitter"
       />
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```